# C++ memcpy: double incompatible with const void

Tags: c++, vector, struct, memcpy

I have a private member

```
vector<double>m_data_content_joinfeatures;
```

and a struct:

```
struct udtJoinFeatures
{
    double Values[16];
};
```

I would now like to copy some values from m_data_content_joinfeatures to a struct of udtJoinFeatures like this:

```
void clsMapping::FeedJoinFeaturesFromMap(udtJoinFeatures &uJoinFeatures)
{

    unsigned int iByteStartPos=1024; //where the data starts that I want to copy
    unsigned int iByteCount=128; //the number of bytes that I want to copy

    memcpy(&uJoinFeatures.Values[0], m_data_content_joinfeatures[iByteStartPos],iByteCount);
}
```

But the compiler tells me that "double is not compatible with the parameter of the kind void*".

Can somebody help? I don't want to use a for-next-statement to copy my values over.
I would like to use MemCpy if possible because I think it is the fastest way.

Thank you!

Comment: Listen to your compiler: a `double` cannot be converted to a `void*`. Your `iByteStartPos` is also either misnamed, or an error.

Comment: Any reason you're not using `std::copy()` for this?

Comment: No particular reason. I am just not experienced with it.

Comment: @tmighty The this is a great opportunity to learn it. Don't use C tools in C++ unless you know you have to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 2nd argument to `memcpy` needs to be an address:

```
&m_data_content_joinfeatures[iByteStartPos]
```

Also, the name `iByteStartPos` seems to imply *byte* offset into the vector. The code you wrote (once fixed to include `&`) will copy starting from the `iByteStartPos` *double* in the vector. If you really want a byte offset, you will need to convert the data start to `const char *` and calculate the address with pointer arithmetic:

```
memcpy(&uJoinFeatures.Values[0],
       reinterpret_cast<const char*>(m_data_content_joinfeatures.data()) + iByteStartPos,
       iByteCount);
```

But once your code begins to look like that, it's a good idea to rethink your strategy and turn away from `memcpy` and byte-based indices, replacing them with safer high-level APIs such as `std::copy`.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a loop at [`memcpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/), you will see that it needs a pointer as a second argument and your giving it a `double`.

Something like:

```
 memcpy(&uJoinFeatures.Values[0], &m_data_content_joinfeatures[iByteStartPos],iByteCount);
 //                               ^
```

should solve this error.

But why don't you use [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy)?

Answer (score 0):

With С++11 you can do

```
memcpy(&uJoinFeatures.Values[0], m_data_content_joinfeatures.data() + iByteStartPos, iByteCount);
```

or even shorter

```
memcpy(uJoinFeatures.Values, m_data_content_joinfeatures.data() + iByteStartPos, iByteCount);
```

Comment: This changes the original problem. The data copied does not reside at the beginning of the sequence.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I missed the index in the question. Edited the answer.